# 403 forbidden When call Azure rest api from a web role instance

Tags: azure

I have a very strange problem. I published a webrole to azure cloud service. In this project, it requires webrole call a Azure Rest API, I can get the response in local emulator but, if I publish it to Azure I get the 403 forbidden Error. I am sure that I installed the certificate to Azure.

This error can be reproduced with following steps:

1. First create a certificate with link below: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651127.aspx
2. Create a cloud service with a webrole, and the certificate in Azure portal, cloud service Certificate and webrole->property->certificate.
3. Publish the project.
4. Remote log in to the web role instance.
5. Create a console application at local then copy the debug folder to remote instance and run the exe in remote application. you can find the application can run perfect in local, but in Azure instance, it seems like it can find certificate, but still get 403 forbidden error.

Console app code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // X.509 certificate variables.
            X509Store certStore = null;
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = null;
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

            // Request and response variables.
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = null;

            // Stream variables.
            Stream responseStream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;

            // URI variable.
            Uri requestUri = null;

            // Specify operation to use for the service management call.
            // This sample will use the operation for listing the hosted services.
            string operation = "hostedservices";

            // The ID for the Windows Azure subscription.
            string subscriptionId = "";

            // The thumbprint for the certificate. This certificate would have been
            // previously added as a management certificate within the Windows Azure management portal.
            string thumbPrint = "";

            // Open the certificate store for the current user.
            certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            // Find the certificate with the specified thumbprint.
            certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                 thumbPrint,
                                 false);

            // Close the certificate store.
            certStore.Close();

            // Check to see if a matching certificate was found.
            if (0 == certCollection.Count)
            {
                throw new Exception("No certificate found containing thumbprint " + thumbPrint);
            }

            // A matching certificate was found.
            certificate = certCollection[0];
            Console.WriteLine("Using certificate with thumbprint: " + thumbPrint);

            // Create the request.
            requestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"
                                 + subscriptionId 
                                 + "/services/" 
                                 + operation);

            httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            // Add the certificate to the request.
            httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

            // Specify the version information in the header.
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2011-10-01");

            // Make the call using the web request.
            httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            // Display the web response status code.
            Console.WriteLine("Response status code: " + httpWebResponse.StatusCode);

            // Display the request ID returned by Windows Azure.
             if (null != httpWebResponse.Headers)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("x-ms-request-id: "
                 + httpWebResponse.Headers["x-ms-request-id"]);
             }

            // Parse the web response.
            responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            // Display the raw response.
            Console.WriteLine("Response output:");
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            // Close the resources no longer needed.
            httpWebResponse.Close(); 
            responseStream.Close(); 
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered: " + e.Message);

            // Exit the application with exit code 1.
            Console.ReadLine();
            System.Environment.Exit(1);

        }
        finally
        {
            // Exit the application.
            Console.ReadLine();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I was running into the same issue using the azure create cert link you provided. I found out that when creating the certificate using that method, the private key was not being uploaded to the cloud service. Even though the service was able to find the certificate, it was still unauthorized when submitting requests.

Using the following method to create a private and public key certificate worked. In the Visual Studio Command Prompt, create a `.cer` and `.pfx` file:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=AzureManage" -sky exchange "AzureManage.cer" -sv "AzureManage.pvk"
pvk2pfx -pvk "AzureManage.pvk" -spc "AzureManage.cer" -pfx "AzureManage.pfx" -pi password
```

The first command creates a private and public key file. You will be prompted for a password a few times. The second command combines the two into a pfx file. If you leave `-pi password` off, then you will be prompted for the password instead of entering it in the terminal.

You'll then want to import the files appropriately:

- Import the pfx into your Local Machine / Personal certificate store using mmc.
- Upload the pfx to the Azure Cloud Service.
- Upload the cer to the Azure Management Certificates store.
- Add the thumbprint of the pfx to your Azure Role Certificates property.

You can then use the Azure management REST API as follows:

```cs
X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint)
{
  var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

  if (certs.Count == 0) return null;
  var cert = certs[0];
  store.Close();
  return cert;
}

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(apiUrl);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2012-03-01");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies with this line of code:

```
certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, **StoreLocation.CurrentUser**);
```

I would expect that a properly uploaded certificate (assuming it was a .pfx that uploaded properly thru the management portal) is stored in the LocalMachine store, not CurrentUser.

Also, in order to read the certificate from the certificate store, your Role needs to run in Full Trust (this can be specified/validated in the Role's project properties in visual studio)

Comment: I don't think this is a problem, I use 
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Cer.cer");
this in local and in role instance(I copied that cer to a role instance) the code can get pass in local, return 403 in role instance.
I don't know why this happen.

Answer (score 0):

+1 @Igorek. I faced similar problem. If I specify that the certificate should be installed in `CurrentUser` store in my configuration, I found that for a Web role the certifcate installs there but for the Worker role the certificate is installed in the `LocalUser` store.

However looks like this is not the root cause of the problem. Can you ensure that the same certificate is there under `Management Certificates` section in the portal (exporting it 1st in cer file format and uploading it there) and the certificate installed in the role has private properties attached to it. These two reasons are primary cause of 403 error.

Comment: THanks for you post.
1， the same application can run in local, so I think the certificate is no problem.
2, the strange thing is, the application shows, in role instance, it can find the certificate in my code, but still can't pass the authentication. Very strange